# I have a form that I want to destroy when the parent form's panel is disposed, how can I do this?

Tags: c#, winforms

The instantiation process is like this:

1. Form (a) is created
2. User selects option which creates a panel with a 2nd form (b) in
3. User clicks a button in 2nd form which creates a child form (c).

I have a button which closes Form 1, however when this is triggered the child form (3) stays alive and doesn't close.

This is item 2 in the list above.

```
private void serialListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var serialForm = new SerialForm();
            SerialFormPanel.Controls.Add(serialForm);
            serialForm.Show();
        }
```

This is item 3 in the list above.

```
private void SerialFormButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var popUp = new PopUp();
            popUp.Show();
        }
```

There is a button on Form (a) which will close Form (a), I want this to also close the pop up created by the button click above.

```
private void changeEnvregionToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var changeEnv = new ChangeEnv();
            changeEnv .Show();
            SerialFormPanel.Dispose();
            this.Close();
        }
```

However the `SerialFormPanel.Dispose();` doesn't close the pop up, and nor does it trigger then `SerialForm_FormClosing` event.

I thought that the reference to the popUp form would be held under the SerialForm's controls variable or within its own variable in the SerialForm object. But I can't seem to find a reference to the popUp object.

When I create a new form using `var popUp = new PopUp(); popUp.Show();` where exactly is the reference to this object instantiated and how can I access it so that I can destroy the popUp form when the serialForm form is also destroyed? Is it created under the scope of the form that instantiated the child form or is it created at a global scope?

Comment: You can't access it, it is a local variable in a method that finished executing a long time ago.  Discovering that you need to store it in a class member is a standard bump on the OOP learning curve.

Comment: @HansPassant So I ended up storing a reference to the pop up form in an instance var, and then doing `var serialForm = (SerialForm) SerialFormPanel.Controls.Find("serialForm", true).First(); serialForm.provisionPopUp.Close();` is that a typical pattern with WinForms? I thought it was a bit hacky personally, but if that's the accepted way to do things then that's cool